# Cannot convert return expression of type 'User' to return type 'User?' for getting currentUser from Firebase

Tags: swift, api, option-type, optional-values, user-identification

I'm new to Swift and I'm having trouble returning a User? value from currentUser in Firebase for CURRENT_USER. I have my User class declaration below and it's located in a separate UserApi file. All the help is greatly appreciated!

```
var CURRENT_USER: User? {
        if let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser {
            return currentUser
        }
        return nil
    }
```

User declaration:

```
class User {
    var email: String?
    var profileImageUrl: String?
    var username: String?
    var id: String?
    var isFollowing: Bool?
}

extension User {
    static func transformUser(dict: [String: Any], key: String) -> User {
        let user = User()
        user.email = dict["email"] as? String
        user.profileImageUrl = dict["profileImageUrl"] as? String
        user.username = dict["username"] as? String
        user.id = key
        return user
    }
}
```

Comment: Kneejerk question, that doesn’t answer yours at all: can you not just return `Auth.auth().currentUser` directly?

Comment: I would, but then I get "Cannot convert return expression of type 'FirebaseAuth.User?' to return type 'RiseUp.User?'" (RiseUp is the name of my project)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have declared a `User` type in your project, the word `User` in `var CURRENT_USER: User? {` gets resolves to your own `User` type, rather than `FirebaseAuth.User`, which is in another module.

To fix this, either:

- rename your own `User` to something such as `UserInfo`, or;
- Add the prefix `FirebaseAuth.` to `User` to differentiate:

  ```
  var currentUser: FirebaseAuth.User? { Auth.auth().currentUser }
  ```

  You can also add a `typealias` to give the Firebase `User` a different name:

  ```
  typealias FirebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.User
  ```